# avoid for loop in python normal(size={}))

Tags: python, numpy, loops, vector, random

My goal is to create an array where each elemet is `normal(size={}))` of each element of `it`.

I am trying to oprimize:

```
it = 2 ** arange(6, 25)
M = zeros(len(it))
for x in range(len(it)):
    M[x] = (normal(size=it[x]))
```

I have these not working so far:

```
N = zeros(len(it))
it = 2 ** arange(6, 25)
N = (normal(size=it))
```

Further I tried:

```
N = (normal(size=it[:]))
```

Provided my data, I believe that such a manual work, or for loop is really inefficient, so I am trying to come up with vectorized operations.

i receive:

```
File "mtrand.pyx", line 1335, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.normal
  File "common.pyx", line 557, in numpy.random.common.cont
ValueError: array is too big; `arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize` is larger than the maximum possible size.
```

Comment: Maybe it helps if you change 25 to a smaller number, e.g. 10

Answer (score 1):

you've not been very precise in where these functions are coming from, but I'm guessing that by `normal(size=it[:])` you mean:

```
import numpy as np
it = 2 ** np.arange(6, 25)
np.random.normal(size=it)
```

which would be telling numpy to create a 19 dimensional array (i.e. `len(it)`) that contains 6 × 10<sup>85</sup> elements (i.e.  `np.prod(it.astype(float))` as floats because the number overflows an int64).  numpy is saying that it can't do that, which seems like a reasonable thing to do.

Numpy doesn't like the ["ragged arrays"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) you're trying to create, neither do most matrix/numeric libraries, hence support is limited!

I'm unsure why you consider that the "loop is really inefficient".  You're creating ~33 million of floats from 19 iterations of a simple Python loop.  The **vast** majority of time will be in highly optimised Numpy library code and some tiny (basically unmeasurable) amount of time will be spent evaluating your Python bytecode.

If you really want a one-liner then you can do:

```
X = [np.random.normal(size=2**i) for i in range(6, 25)]
```

which makes the split between Numpy and Python worlds more obvious.

Note that on my laptop, the Python code executes in ~5µs while the Numpy code runs for ~800ms.  So you're trying to optimise the 0.0006% part!

Note that it's not always a win to use Numpy's vectorization, it only helps with larger arrays, for example the above loop is "faster" than:

```
X = [np.random.normal(i) for i in 2**np.arange(6, 25)]
```

4.8 vs 5.1 µs for the Python code, because of the time spent marshalling objects into/out of the Numpy world.  Again, none of this matters, just use whichever solution makes your code easier to understand.  A few microseconds is nothing compared to seconds.

Comment: Thanks, my actual task requires:
```for x in range(len(it)):
    M[x] = sum(normal(size=it[x]))
```
Which I know changes the question, but still might be relevant to ask.